# Direct proof of "Nuclear implies $C_{red}^*(G) \cong C^*(G)$"

Tags: gr.group-theory, oa.operator-algebras, tensor-products

It is well-known that for a discrete group $G$ the following statements are equivalent:

- $C_{red}^*(G)$ nuclear
- $C_{red}^*(G) \cong C^*(G)$ canonically i.e. there exists an *-isomorphism between the full and the reduced group $C^*$-algebras extending the identity on the corresponding conolution algebra.

All proves of this I have seen so far show a chain of equivalent statements usually starting with assuming amenability of the group $G$ (which is also equivalent).

For me the two statements above seem to be of the same flavour therefore I'm wondering if there is a (short) direct way to see the equivalence (or at least the implication of (i) to (ii)).

Comment: Maybe you can say which definition of nuclear $C^*$-algebra you're starting with?

Comment: I'm thinking of nuclearity in terms of tensor product norms (i.e. $C_{red}^*(W) \cong B$ has a unique $C^*$norm for any $C^*$-algebra), but it's not that important for my question. Proofs using other characterizations are appreciated as well

Comment: Also the well-known (and important) statement is not that $C^*$red(W) and $C^*$(W) are isomorphic, but that the canonical map $C^*$(W)$\to C^*$red(W) is an isomorphism. Possibly the other claim is true (that they're not isomorphic at all) as well for arbitrary non-amenable groups, but it is less natural (more anecdotical), and not well-known.

Comment: You're right. I changed my original question to make it more clear

Comment: Actually the identity on the group algebra has a unique extension (by density) to a continuous $*$-homomorphism  $C^*(G)\to C^*_{red}(G)$, which is surjective for every group $G$.

Comment: Yes, that is clear by the definition of the full norm. It only remains to show that nuclearity implies that the map is isometric

Comment: The second condition is the weak containment equivalence of amenability phrased in C*-language.  So it looks like you want a direct proof that $C^*_r(G)$ nuclear implies amenability of G (right?).  I don't know if it fits your definition of short but Lance's original proof is direct ("On Nuclear C*-algebras" JFA 1973)

Comment: @YCor Yes, that other claim is true.  Once there is any isomorphism you have that the left regular representation weakly contains the trivial representation.

Comment: @CalebEckhardt The OP seems to want a way to bypass amenability of G, although it's not clear to me what counts as such. Put another way: IIRC, Lance shows that the CPAP implies there is an invariant mean on $\ell^\infty(G)$. But going from that to the weak containment version is not quite direct (IMO)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following direct proof uses Fell's absorption principle, as well as its (easy) corollary: the "diagonal" map $C^\ast(G) \hookrightarrow C^\ast_r(G) \otimes_{\max{}} C^\ast_r(G)$ is injective (see Theorem 8.2 in Pisier's book).

$(i) \Rightarrow (ii)$: If $C^\ast_r(G)$ is nuclear, then the composition
\begin{equation}
C^\ast(G) \to C^\ast_r(G) \otimes_{\max{}} C^\ast_r(G) = C^\ast_r(G) \otimes_{\min{}} C^\ast_r(G) \subseteq \mathbb B(\ell^2(G) \otimes \ell^2(G))
\end{equation}
is faithful, and this representation is $\lambda \times \lambda$ where $\lambda$ is the left regular representation. By Fell's absorption, $\lambda \times \lambda$ and $\lambda \times I$ are equivalent, where $I$ is the trivial representation, so $\lambda \colon C^\ast(G) \to \mathbb B(\ell^2(G))$ is faithful. Hence $C^\ast(G) = C^\ast_r(G)$.

$(ii)\Rightarrow (i)$: Assume $C^\ast(G) = C^\ast_r(G)$, or even weaker, that the trivial representation $\tau \colon C^\ast_r(G) \to \mathbb C$ is well-defined. Let $D$ be an arbitrary $C^\ast$-algebra. Let $\pi_G \colon C^\ast_r(G) \to \mathbb B(H)$ and $\pi_D \colon D \to \mathbb B(H)$ be representations with commuting images such that $\pi := \pi_G \times \pi_D \colon C^\ast_r(G) \otimes_{\max{}} D \to \mathbb B(H)$ is faithful. Note that we have a faithful representation
\begin{equation}
\lambda \otimes \pi \colon C^\ast_r(G) \otimes_{\min{}} (C^\ast_r(G) \otimes_{\max{}} D) \to \mathbb B(\ell^2(G) \otimes H).
\end{equation}
Hence we get
\begin{eqnarray*}
\| \sum_{i=1}^n u_{g_i} \otimes d_i\|_{C^\ast_r(G)\otimes_{\max{}} D} &=& \| \sum_{i=1}^n \tau(u_{g_i}) \otimes (u_{g_i} \otimes d_i)\|_{\mathbb C \otimes_{\min{}} (C^\ast_r(G)\otimes_{\max{}} D)} \\
&\leq& \| \sum_{i=1}^n u_{g_i} \otimes (u_{g_i} \otimes d_i)\|_{C^\ast_r(G) \otimes_{\min{}} (C^\ast_r(G)\otimes_{\max{}} D)} \\
&=& \|\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda(g_i)\otimes \pi_G(u_{g_i}) \pi_D(d_i) \|_{\mathbb B(\ell^2(G) \otimes H)}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Let $U\in \mathbb B(\ell^2(G) \otimes H)$ be the unitary given by
\begin{equation}
U\delta_g \otimes \xi = \delta_g \otimes \pi_G(g) \xi.
\end{equation}
Note that this unitary implements a unitary equivalence $\lambda \times \pi_G \sim \lambda \times I$.
As $\pi_G$ and $\pi_D$ have commuting images, it easily follows that $U$ and $1\otimes \pi_D$ commute. Hence
\begin{eqnarray*}
&& \|U^\ast \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda(g_i)\otimes \pi_G(u_{g_i}) \pi_D(d_i) U \|_{\mathbb B(\ell^2(G) \otimes H)}\\
&=& \| \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda(g_i) \otimes \pi_D(d_i)\|_{\mathbb B(\ell^2(G) \otimes H)} \\
&=& \| \sum_{i=1}^n u_{g_i} \otimes d_i\|_{C^\ast_r(G) \otimes_{\min{}} D}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Thus $C^\ast_r(G) \otimes_{\max{}} D = C^\ast_r(G) \otimes_{\min{}} D$, so $C^\ast_r(G)$ is nuclear.